# Swift - Passing data form UITextField to TextView in another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I know, the topic of this question was asked several times before but I don't get the right solution for my problem, so I hope someone can help me.

I have two `viewControllers`. In `firstVC`, I change my text with an `textView`. This text is stored in `UserDefaults`. So now, I'd like to display the stored text on my `secondVC` in a `textView`.

My code for `firstVC`:

```
class editprofileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var changeTextInput: UITextField!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stringKey = UserDefaults.standard
        changeTextInput.text = stringKey.string(forKey: "savedStringKey")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func change(_ sender: Any) {

        let myText = changeTextInput.text;
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }

}
```

Here I write the text in the textfield and store it.

My `secondVC`:

```
    self.bioTxt.text = // here should be the text from firstVC
    bioTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    bioTxt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you pushing to second vc through code or segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView! //your textView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//MARK: - Button Action
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userDefaultStore = UserDefaults.standard //userDefault object
    userDefaultStore.set(txtView.text, forKey: "key_Value") //store textView value in userDefault

    //navigate secondViewController
    let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
}
```

**Second ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView! // your textView
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard //create UserDefault object

        txtView.text = userDefault.string(forKey: "key_Value")!//get userdefault value using same key which used to store date and set in textView
        txtView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing in `USerDeaults` everytime is not encourageable. Remember that User defaults can hold a small amount of data. The only highly required information you can put into this.

Coming to your scenario, if you are navigating from **FirstVC** to **SecondVC** every time, then just add one variable globally on second view controller and assign in firstView controller before navigating to second view controller.

Comment: in my case i used this and it working fine, but i want to get this variable in all viewControllers so navigating is impossible... any other way

Answer (score -1):

You can user  `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: )` function to get the value stored in `UserDefaults`. Try this

```
self.bioTxt.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedStringKey")
```